# Python 2.7 Global name not defined

Tags: python

Writing a python program to perform merge sort, and I get a Global Name not found error

```
### Program for Merge Sort ###
def merge(numbers, l, m, r):
    n1 = m-l-1 ### Size of the left side array ###
    n2 = r-l  ### Size of the right side array ###
    ### Temporary Lists ###
    for i in range(n1):
        L[i] = numbers[l+i]

    for j in range(n2):
        R[j] =  numbers[m+j+1]

    ### The following code eliminates searching if any of the lists have become empty ###
    L[n1] = float("inf")
    R[n1] = float("inf")

    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(l,r+1):
        if(L[i]<=R[j]):
            numbers[k] = L[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            numbers[k] = R[j]
            j+=1

def mergeSort(numbers, l, r):
    if (l<r):
        m = l+(r-1)/2 ### Avoids overflow for large numbers
        mergeSort(numbers, l, m)
        mergeSort(numbers, m+1, r)
        merge(numbers, l, m, r)
```

I have my driver program calling the mergeSort function on the user input numbers and when I run the code, I get an error saying **Global Name 'R' is not defined**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_sort.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "merge_sort.py", line 50, in main
    mergeSort(numbers, 0, size-1)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 32, in mergeSort
    mergeSort(numbers, l, m)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 33, in mergeSort
    mergeSort(numbers, m+1, r)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 34, in mergeSort
    merge(numbers, l, m, r)
  File "merge_sort.py", line 10, in merge
    R[j] =  numbers[m+j+1]
NameError: global name 'R' is not defined`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly what the error tells you: you are using a variable named `R` that hasn't been defined.

Comment: If L and R are meant to be global variables, then you need to declare them as such with a "global L,R" statement.

Comment: @BartoszKP Do I need to initialize the list `R` or something? And I'm also using `L` as a list, do I need to do the same for it?

Comment: @chaos_theory You need to read (or reread) a Python tutorial :) Don't mean to be rude, but it's really one of the most basic things, always covered in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you never defined name `R`.  Fix that by replacing:

```
for j in range(n2):
    R[j] =  numbers[m+j+1]
```

with:

```
R = [numbers[m+j+1] for j in range(n2)]
```

(and similarly for `L`, by the way -- I'm surprised you don't get **that** as an error since you access the name `L` before the name `R`).

Comment: Yes, I was confused with that too, since `L` was also left undeclared.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your temporary lists, `L` and `R`, before using them.

```
L = []
R = []
for i in range(n1):
    L[i] = numbers[l+i]

for j in range(n2):
    R[j] =  numbers[m+j+1]
```